# Regex - "If-Then-Else Conditionals" in Notepad ++ or any supported environement

Tags: regex

I have an regular expression which extract the last character of an string.

I have to convert the last character of the string as per condition. 
Condition : 0 --> { 1 --> A 2 --> B 3 --> C

**Example**
Input : `1001{ 10011 10012 10013`
Output : `10010 1001A 1001B 1001C`

I need to do this using regular expression, so what should be the regular expression to "find" the last character of the String and what should be the "replace" part of the regular expression.

The regex I was using to find the last character of a string is `"\S(?!\S)"`.

Comment: `(?:(\{)|(1)|(2)|(3))(?!\S)` = > `(?{1}0:?{2}A:?{3}B:C)`

Comment: I have seen the link for which my question has been marked as duplicate but it does not gives me a brief description of how to write the conditional part in regex. Can you please help me to provide me the condition for my scenario raised.

Comment: Thank you so much Wiktor....!!!!